# Is there an area in CiviCRM (or a way) for people involved in a case to communicate privately?

Tags: wordpress, civicase, configuration

When a new case is set up, we need to let the parties involved with that case communicate privately and have their messages and shared docs only accessible to them? Like a shared, but private, message board. Is this possible without using an 'outside' tool?

Comment: Hi Aaron, interesting question - so like a 'room' for each case so a threaded or non-threaded discussion can occur? Nothing that refined and I assume having an Activity of type = Discussion, and, if using Drupal, then having a View that strings them together wouldn't suffice (but is how i would approach it in Drupal)

Comment: also just confirming that only those folk involved with the Case should be seeing any Case related Activities or Documents anyway

Comment: also be aware this is great for files on Cases -  https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/using-and-improving-the-documents-extension-a-drupal-extension-by-civicoop

Comment: but is primarily built around Drupal webforms

Comment: sorry - just seeing the wordpress tag now

Comment: Thank you for the great responses. I am going to try using BuddyPress (and/or bbPress) to solve this. I will post how/if it works well... after I try it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add BuddyPress in and with the additional BuddyPress CiviCRM plugins it will sync users.  Think Facebook and you've got the idea.  You can make things private or not, do PM's, do groups, etc.

Comment: To clarify, the two profile sync plugins https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-xprofile-wp-user-sync/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-profile-sync/ would take care of the Contact <--> User sync. The relevant Contacts can be added to a group programatically when a new case is created, and then https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-groups-civicrm-sync/ will sync them between a BuddyPress group and two CiviCRM "Mailing List" and "ACL" groups (and vice versa). Group-specific docs can be created using https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-docs/

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at iflychat. It's technically an outside tool but can be embedded in wordpress so appears as if it's part of the site. It can have private chat rooms and files. https://iflychat.com/installation/wordpress-chat-plugin. It also has drupal and joomla plugins.